# Can search-index be used for a project running on Node.js using mysql as database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, indexing, full-text-search

I have been looking for a suitable implementation of full text search for my application running on Node.js using MySQL as database. I have considered various options:
clucene - however, this has not been updated for a long time
lunr.js - more suitable for smaller data searches as it uses front end processing

Currently, the most hopeful one seems to be [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index), but I am not sure whether it can be implemented when the project is using MySQL as DB instead of LevelDB. According to what i found online, any database that are levelUP compliant (and a "Down" component) would work.

Does anyone has experience implementing search-index using MySQL? It'll be great to hear any suggestions regarding this, or any other full text search packages that works with Node.js and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely use `search-index` with mysql, in fact they make a great fit.

Use the [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs) package, and check out: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#piping-results-with-streams2 . This will allow you to do the following:

```js
connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts')
  .stream({highWaterMark: 5})
  .pipe(mySearchIndex.defaultPipeline())
  .pipe(mySearchIndex.add()) // <- mysql docs are now searchable in mySearchIndex
```